# Грамотно ли выражение "признательные показания"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Уместно ли в данном случае слово "признательные", обозначающее признательность, а не признание?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Признательные показания ― это юридический жаргон или юридический термин?

Статья на эту тему: [Юридический жаргон: понятие, примеры, оценка Туранин В.Ю. | siberia-expert.com](http://siberia-expert.com/publ/konferencii/konferencija_2010/juridicheskij_zhargon_ponjatie_primery_ocenka_v_ju/9-1-0-305)

**Автор делает вывод о недопустимости такого явления и не считает выражение "признательные показания" даже юридически грамотным** (однако вопрос остается открытым).

"Юридический жаргон ― это искусственно созданная юристами система слов и выражений, предназначенная для обозначения юридических понятий **в нетипичной** для литературного языка форме. 
Основной сферой использования юридического жаргона является юридический разговорный язык, где активно задействованы такие жаргонизмы, как «опер» (оперативный уполномоченный сотрудник), «вещдок» (вещественное доказательство), «незаконные бандформирования», «**признательные показания**» и другие.

Само слово «признательный» может использоваться только **лишь в значении «испытывающий признательность к кому-, чему-либо, благодарный; выражающий признательность».** Очевидно, что это никак не корреспондирует тому значению, которое вкладывается в термин «признательные показания» в юридической среде (сознаться в чём–либо и рассказать об этом). С нашей точки зрения, в данном случае правильнее использовать выражение «**осуществить признание**».

Из юридического разговорного языка жаргон **проникает и в язык подзаконных и правоприменительных актов.** К примеру, термин «признательные показания» используется **в тексте распоряжения Федеральной таможенной службы РФ от 28 июля 2006 года № 257-р** «Об утверждении регламента действий должностных лиц таможенных органов при обнаружении фактов незаконного перемещения автотранспортных средств через таможенную границу Российской Федерации»

Comment: Простите, хотела посмотреть Вашу ссылку, но она не открывается. Как быть?

Comment: Я набрала еще раз адрес, вроде бы открывается. Или в Яндексе: Юридический жаргон: понятие, примеры, оценка

Comment: Теперь все в порядке. Благодарю за интересный материал.

Answer (score 0):

Признательные показания = покаянные  - профессионализм следователей и оперативных работников от глагола признаться, покаяться. Есть в криминалистической  энциклопедии, следовательно, вполне грамотное, как и "расколол", но если мы начинаем использовать их как нейтральные фразы в разговоре и переписке в быту, это считается стилистической ошибкой, просторечием.